# Can't deploy nodes on slaves with daemon set installed

Tags: kubernetes

Soo to resume the situation, i created a kubernetes cluster with one master and on slaves.
I installed everything to need it to work (Pod Network Calico here and dashbord for better management)

I tried to install a virtual IP service to just create a virtual IP for the service i deploy in my cluster but when i installed the daemonset (kube-keepalived-vip here), everytime i deploy a service it never get shedule on the slave. But the virtual IP is working properly because i can access my service thougth this IP.

To clarify the situation, my master is untained soo i can deploy pods on it.

Soo here i try to have HighAvailability services with the same virtual IP. Without the Daemonset, the LoadBalancing is working properly when i deploy a service in my cluster and the pods are sheduled on the slaves.

If you know what's wrong or what to do, let me know

Comment: Do you see `Ready` status on the slave when running `kubectl get nodes`?

Comment: Yep the slaves and the master are ready, the kube-dns is up and every other critical pods too. It's just the moment i install a daemonset. Even when i checked the logs of the daemon-set, it's working properly. I got 0 message error

Comment: It's like i'm mission something in the configurations of the nodes

Comment: What's the output of `kubectl get ds -n <namespace>` ?

Comment: root@sca4-rt:/home/ronce# kubectl get ds --all-namespaces
default kube-keepalived-vip   2    2     2     2     2    cluster=theo    8d
kube-system   calico-etcd      1     1     1     1     1      node-role.kubernetes.io/master=  15d
kube-system   calico-node     2     2     1     2     1    <none> 15d
kube-system   kube-proxy      2     2     2     2     2    <none> 15d PS : It was too long i delete some useless lines

Comment: To be short, they are all running and up on the both servers. (I just saw just after is made this command the calico-node was 2 2 2 2 2 and not 2 2 1 2 1 on the logs i post just before. I just started the servers and make this command after.)